# how to trigger the Terminal to full screen whenever ./myscript.sh is launched

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

I'm writing a bash script that run some process inside Terminal.app provided by OS X, so the interaction with it basically comes from a user being at the Terminal itself.

Whenever we `$ ./myScript.sh` I need the Terminal to go Full Screen. 
if someone could give me an example for some bash script to trigger full screen when called it be awesome...
any thought? :-)

Comment: Hi, I guess you mean terminal emulators running shell (bash, zsh, csh etc.). Please specify the type of emulator you using.

Comment: well  I'm running `/bin/bash`

Comment: Sorry, in which GUI emulator? I guess this - Terminal (Terminal.app) is the terminal emulator included in the macOS operating system by Apple.

Comment: that is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding this line inside your script:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "System events" to keystroke "f" using {command down, control down}'
```

It toggles *"Full screen mode"* so you can use it again at the end to revert out of *"Full screen mode"* again.

It is the same as typing <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+F.

---

If you can't work out how to edit your original script, or you don't want to, you can put a wrapper around it like this.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Toggle full screen
osascript -e 'tell application "System events" to keystroke "f" using {command down, control down}'

./YourOriginalScript "$@"

# Toggle full screen
osascript -e 'tell application "System events" to keystroke "f" using {command down, control down}'
```

Save the above as `wrapper`, make it executable with:

```
chmod +x wrapper
```

Then run your script with the wrapper around it as follows:

```
./wrapper
```

Comment: Well, I've added it to my script but nothing happens;
Also tried to trigger in from the Terminal.app cli and received an error: `82:84: syntax error: A “}” can’t go after this “}”. (-2740)` any idea?

Comment: So what happens if you hold down `cmd` and `ctrl` and while holding them, you tap `f`?

Comment: It goes fullscreen

Comment: Are you definitely using **Terminal** and not **iTerm**? Can you copy the command from my answer and paste it straight into **Terminal**?

Comment: I have added a way of wrapping your original script in a *"full-screen wrapper"*, - not just 50cent, but the full dollar ;-)

Comment: Please try and give a bit more feedback else it is very hard to help. What do you mean *"Doesn't work"*? Does it run at all? Are there error messages? What happens? Maybe you can show your script?

Answer (score -1):

You probably need to install **xdotool** or **cliclick**

When installed add to your script:

```
xdotool key Ctrl+Cmd+F
```

or

```
cliclick ku:ctrl,cmd,f
```

Comment: If you try using your suggested `cliclick` command, you will find that it will not accept the `f` the way you show? Also, a `key up` command without a preceding `key down` doesn't seem intuitive to me anyway?